# Gridview fixed header cloneNode hidden field value getting duplicate by comma separated

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I Have grid view with multiple hidden field which was using to calculation on rowdatabound but while i am making header of that gridview fixed with DivHR.appendChild(tbl.cloneNode(true)); its make hidden field value with comma separated duplicate value i.e 2,2 and 0,0

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function MakeStaticHeader(gridId, height, width, headerHeight, isFooter) {
var tbl = document.getElementById(gridId);
    if (tbl) {
    var DivHR = document.getElementById('DivHeaderRow');
    var DivMC = document.getElementById('DivMainContent');
    var DivFR = document.getElementById('DivFooterRow');
    //*** Set divheaderRow Properties ****
    DivHR.style.height = headerHeight + 'px';
    DivHR.style.width = (parseInt(width)-16) + 'px';
    DivHR.style.position = 'relative';
    DivHR.style.top = '0px';
    DivHR.style.zIndex = '10';
    DivHR.style.verticalAlign = 'top';
    //*** Set divMainContent Properties ****
    DivMC.style.width = width + 'px';
    DivMC.style.height = height + 'px';
    DivMC.style.position = 'relative';
    DivMC.style.top = -headerHeight+ 'px';
    DivMC.style.zIndex = '1';
    //*** Set divFooterRow Properties ****
    DivFR.style.width = (parseInt(width) -16) + 'px';
    DivFR.style.position = 'relative';       
    DivFR.style.paddingtop = '2px';
    if (isFooter) {
        var tblfr = tbl.cloneNode(true);
        tblfr.removeChild(tblfr.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]);
        var tblBody = document.createElement('tbody');
        tblfr.style.width = '100%';
        tblfr.cellSpacing = "0";
        tblfr.border = "0px";
        tblfr.rules = "none";
        //*****In the case of Footer Row *******
        tblBody.appendChild(tbl.rows[tbl.rows.length - 1]);
        tblfr.appendChild(tblBody);
        DivFR.appendChild(tblfr);
    }
    //****Copy Header in divHeaderRow****
    DivHR.appendChild(tbl.cloneNode(true));
}
}
  function OnScrollDiv(Scrollablediv) {
document.getElementById('DivHeaderRow').scrollLeft = Scrollablediv.scrollLeft;
document.getElementById('DivFooterRow').scrollLeft = Scrollablediv.scrollLeft;
}
```

i want hidden field value should be as it is like original